# Find continuous function with minimum

Tags: continuity

Let $f$ be a function continuous on ${[x_1,x_2]}$ with the minimum equal $y$. Find the functions $f$ such that min of ${f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=}$ min of ${f(x)}$

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about the problem?

Comment: I suppose it lacks some information. We have to see the codomain  if we can have f(1/x) and if 1/x reaches its limit there. I can't solve it if it needs superior analysis

Comment: You use the letter $f$ for different purposes. – Go back to the source of your problem and make sure that you have copied everything, and correctly.

Comment: I meant $f$ not f

Comment: @Jack, before I offer any assistance, I would like to see your thoughts on the problem. What do you know about extrema of continuous functions on closed domains?